# Subclassing UILabel in RubyMotion to set attributedText kerning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, rubymotion

I need to support custom kerning for some of my labels that are being added through Interface Builder (IB).  The custom class is set on the Label in IB and the text is set there as well.  Attempting to override the `text` property with the `attributedText` property is not working.

This is working fine for my `UIButton` subclass, but a similar technique is not behaving with `UILabel`.

The `attributedText` property does not seem to have any affect when set in `awakeFromNib` or `drawRect:rect`.

Example

```
class KernedLabel < UILabel

  def awakeFromNib
    super

    attributed_text = NSMutableAttributedString.alloc
      .initWithString("Atributed Text")

    attributed_text.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName,
                                 value: 1.0,
                                 range: [0, attributed_text.length])

    attributedText = attributed_text
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me with one minor change: you need to use `self.attributedText =` (calling the method on `self`):

```
def awakeFromNib
  super

  attributed_text = NSMutableAttributedString.alloc
    .initWithString("Atributed Text")

  attributed_text.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName,
                               value: 1.0,
                               range: [0, attributed_text.length])

  self.attributedText = attributed_text
end
```

Comment: Of course, it's a setter method vs a property.  I don't see the kerning being applied though, did you in your test?

Comment: Yes, that exact code above produced text with extra spacing between each letter (on iOS 7)